# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x\cdot \sin(2x)}{(1+\cos(4x^2))}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, contest-math

Do you have a tip to accomplish this integral?

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x\cdot \sin(2x)}{(1+\cos(4x^2))}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
I already tried by substitution and by parts, neither gave me a light how to solve it.

This is a multiple choice question from an Olympiad. The options are A) $\pi/2$, B) $\pi^2/4$, C) $\pi/8$ and D) $\pi^2/16$.

Comment: $u = \cos(4x^2)$ looks helpful

Comment: @SenZen why do you think that it is helpful? Maybe you could elaborate further

Comment: Since the denominator is $0$ for two values of $x$ in the interval of integration (at $x=\sqrt{\pi/4}$ and $x=\sqrt{3\pi/4}$), the integral doesn't exist. What is the origin of this problem?

Comment: Are you sure about $4x^2$ ? Could it be $4x$ ?

Comment: It is a olympic problem! I will post below a print. Probably i read wrong so, but i think is not my fault, normally $$cos^{2}(2x)$$ would be used to represent the square of the cos, but it was used different, see below.

Comment: From the image, I believe the denominator should read as $1 +\left( \cos(2x) \right)^2 = 1 + \cos^2 (2x)$, in which case the answer should be $D$.

Comment: @DatBoi It's not helpful.

Comment: @SenZen ofcourse....the erratum is yet another deal...

Answer (score 2):

Gabriela. Welcome to our community!

At first, you understood the problem incorrect. They ask you to evaluate such integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi /2} \frac{x \sin (2x)}{1+\cos^2 (2x)}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{t \sin (t)}{1+\cos^2 (t)}dt.$$
It's easier to get rid of those $2x$ before going further.

Now consider such integral first:
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{ \sin (x)}{1+\cos^2 (x)}dx= [\text{  substitute } t=\cos (x)]=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
It's a common integral, hope you will get the main idea.

Now get back to your problem. The trick here is to substitute $z=\pi-t$:
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{t \sin (t)}{1+\cos^2 (t)}dt = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\pi-z) \sin (z)}{1+\cos^2 (z)}dz=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin (z)}{1+\cos^2 (z)}dz- \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{z \sin (z)}{1+\cos^2 (z)}dz.$$

Now you'll probably notice similarities. Donate your integral as $I$, then:

$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin (z)}{1+\cos^2 (z)}dz-I\implies I=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin (z)}{1+\cos^2 (z)}dz=\frac{\pi}{8} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}.$$

So your answer ir $D$.

Answer (score 0):

The integration over the odd integrand after the variable change vanishes
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi /2} \frac{x \sin 2x}{1+\cos^2 2x}dx
&\overset{x=t+\frac\pi4}=\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4} \frac{(t+\frac\pi4)\cos 2t}{1+\sin^2 2t}dt\\
&= \frac\pi4\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4} \frac{\cos 2t}{1+\sin^2 2t}dt=\frac\pi8\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4} \frac{d(\sin 2t)}{1+\sin^2 2t}dt\\
&= \frac\pi8 \tan^{-1}\sin2t\bigg|_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}
=\frac\pi8\cdot \frac\pi2=\frac{\pi^2}{16}
\end{align}